# Add Custom Files to a Package to be installed on specific paths with productbuild/pkgbuild?

Tags: macos, package, mdm, pkgbuild, productbuild

I rebuild an existing pkg with productbuild.

My root path looks like this: ROOT > Applications/Scripts/Library/private/

In Applications/ is my .app , which works.
However in Library for example is another folder "Desktop Pictures" and there is a background.png. I would like to have that exact path with the .png on the device that i install this package, so i can use it later for automatically set the background.

Not working tho

This is how the first pkg gets build:

```
pkgbuild --root "ROOT" \
--identifier "${IDENTIFIER}" \
--install-location "/" \
"${PACKAGE_NAME}_before.pkg"
```

this is how i rebuild it

```
productbuild \
--distribution distribution.dist \
--scripts "ROOT/Scripts" \
--sign "${IDENTITY}" \
--package-path "${PACKAGE_NAME}_before.pkg" \
"${PACKAGE_NAME}.pkg"
```

Comment: What is your folder structure in "ROOT"?

Comment: I just got the "ROOT" folder there, and then a script to build that pkg. Also the pkg that gets build and send to another device via MDM.

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your question.  You simply want a `background.png` file to be installed in the `/Applications/Scripts/Library/Desktop Pictures/` directory?

Comment: No no.. In Root there are the folders "Application", and "Scripts" and "Library" and "private". And serveral following folder-structures where files are. For example : ROOT/Library/Desktop Pictures/my.png .

Comment: Gotcha.  And when you install the package, you're not seeing ROOT/Library/Desktop Pictures/my.png?

Comment: Yes thats right. Probably because i have no rights to put anything in that path when installing a package.... SIP or something. It's only not happening in that case, when i install the package remote with MDM. When i install it manually on the other device, its working since i have admin rights (?) i guess